# Delete rows in Excel if it doesn't match

Tags: vba, excel

Not sure how to do this, I have an Excel sheet that imports emails in 2's - but sometimes it only imports 1 email, so I would like those lines deleted -

1@email1
1@email1
2@email2
2@email2
3@email3 - need deleted since it's only 1 entry
4@email4
4@email4

---

It's importing from a CSV - I need it to delete the row if it doesn't match, because there should be 2 of the same email addresses imported  - so

```
if A2=A1 it's good  
if A2 doesn't = A1 Delete row A1  
if A4=A3 it's good  
if A4 doesn't = A3 Delete row A3  
if A6=A5 it's good  
if A6 doesn't = A5 Delete row A5
```

Comment: This is too vague. Are you wanting to modify the import process so that it doesn't import single emails, or are you wanting to create post-import functionality which will clean out the single emails? If the former, please post your code.

Comment: Add a column using COUNTIF() to count the number of instances, then sort and delete the rows with 1's

Comment: On Linux, it is a one liner with `sort file.txt | uniq -d` to print out duplicates

Comment: So i guess it would be if a2 doesn't =a1 delete a1, if a4 doesn't =a3 delete a3, a6 doesn't =a5 delete a5....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty straightforward in VBA, if I understand the problem.  You just want to remove rows that are not followed with an identical email address, right?

```
a = 1
Do
  b = a + 1
  If Cells(a, 1).Value <> Cells(b, 1).Value Then
    Rows(a).Delete
  Else
    a = a + 2
  End If
Loop Until a > Sheets(1).Rows.Count
```

Not the most elegant, all purpose solution I'll admit, but quick and easy.

Comment: I tried to vote 2 answers, I guess when I did that, since I voted for yours first, it unvoted it when I went to vote the other - so lesson learned... I can only vote for 1 :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can programmatically remove those values from cells in Excel using something like [Apache POI-HSSF](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) It allows you to read and modify Excel worksheets using Java. Look at the Usermodel API it sounds like what you are looking for.

You can also take a look at [JExcel Here](http://www.teamdev.com/downloads/jexcel/javadoc/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data is column A

```
Sub Deletes()
Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Range("a1").Select
For i = 1 To lastrow
If ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value <> ActiveCell.Value Then
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete    
End If
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select
Next
End Sub
```

tested and working fine.

Comment: Glad it worked perfectly. Why dont you vote the answer?